# Concatenation error - collation conflict between concat operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query but it's giving an error.

**Query**

```
Select [Material],CONCAT(case when len([PO Item]) = 3 then '00' when len([PO Item]) = 2 then '000' else '0000' end,[PO Item]) from Vendortable
```

**Error**

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the
>   concat operation.

What I want to do it append 0's at the front of the number to make it a 5 digit number.

What is this error? how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have different default collation and [PO Item] collation, so `'00', '000', '0000'` get different

force same collation

```
Select [Material],
    CONCAT(
        case 
            when len([PO Item]) = 3 then '00' 
            when len([PO Item]) = 2 then '000' 
        else 
            '0000' 
        end collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
        [PO Item] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) 
from Vendortable
```

but.. in general, for padding numbers i prefer to use:

```
 select RIGHT('00000' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + [PO Item] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 5) 
 from Vendortable
```

Answer (score 2):

[Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) refers to the rules that govern how SQL compares and sorts strings, for example when sorting rows by a string is `ấ` treated the same as `a`, or is it sorted separately? Collation determines that, among many other things.  When comparing two columns, their collation must match so SQL Server knows which one to use.

These rules are usually the same within a database (the "default collation"), but often if you have merged databases, upgraded a legacy database and added to it, or someone has changed default collations on a column then two columns in the same database could have different collations.  As @MtwStark has pointed out, you can force collation for a particular comparison, and if absolutely necessary, you can [change the collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation) on one column to match another.

It appears to me that your database default collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, and your column collation on the `[PO Item]` column is `Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS`, hence the error.

I also agree that using the `right()` function is better for padding to the left:

```
select right('00000' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
         + [PO Item] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 5) 
from Vendortable
```

A word of warning though - don't alter database or column collation unless you know what you are doing, or you could create a world of trouble (been there).  If this is a persistent issue with your database, get a good DBA to look at it and advise a solution.