# Using CAST, CONCAT and COLLATE with a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to CONCAT two columns and also use CAST and COLLATE but keep getting a host of different errors when I try to fix them in a way I think would work.

Basically I am trying to CONCAT two columns together but I get a collation conflict. So then, I try and COLLATE the two columns and I then get a datatype is invalid for COLLATE error. After this I try to CAST the column giving me the error to change it to a varchar but it doesn't work. I'm just unsure how to make all 3 work together.

```
SELECT TransactionHeader.TransactionType,
TransactionHeader.TicketStub,
CAST ( TransactionHeader.TransactionNumber AS nvarchar(8)) AS [TN],
TransactionHeader.ActualAmount,
Currencies.SwiftCode,
TransactionHeader.CurrencyID,
Divisions.ShortName,
DealHeader.StartDateNumber,
DealHeader.EndDateNumber,

CONCAT (TransactionHeader.TicketStub,                 
TransactionHeader.TransactionNumber) AS [DealRef]

FROM   Company.dbo.TransactionHeader TransactionHeader
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company.dbo.DealHeader DealHeader
    ON TransactionHeader.THDealID=DealHeader.DHDealID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company.dbo.Currencies Currencies
    ON TransactionHeader.CurrencyID=Currencies.CRRecordID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company.dbo.Divisions Divisions
    ON TransactionHeader.PrimaryPartyID=Divisions.DVRecordID

WHERE TransactionHeader.TicketStub COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
= TransactionHeader.TransactionNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

All in all, I just want to CONCAT the TicketStub and TransactionNumber Columns but I am not sure how to get past the errors I'm getting. As far as the COLLATE goes I'm still kind of usnsure how it even works, I just know to fix the collation error I need to do it. I am very new to T-SQL and have only been writing it for the past month and a half so please, any advice at all would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Collation is a setting that determines how a DB should treat character data at either the server, database, or column level. There's a really good blog on this at [red-gate.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/questions-sql-server-collations-shy-ask/). Each server, and database, will have a collation. It's common for the databases and server to match, since by default a database will inherit this setting from the `model` database. It is uncommon to see [column level collation](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/questions-sql-server-collations-shy-ask/#post-70501-_Toc479001448), but that seems to be what you have here since all of your tables are coming from the same `DATABASE`.

You will need to figure out what the collation is on those columns. Dave Pinal has a good [write up on this on his blog.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/) You can also do this a few other ways. [See the docs for that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information?view=sql-server-2017)

Once you have your collation, you can then collate the `CONCAT`. It will look something like the below. Here I just use the `DATABASE_DEFUALT` which would probably work in your case:

```
CONCAT(TransactionHeader.TicketStub COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,TransactionHeader.TransactionNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS [DealRef]
```

You can find more examples of [`COLLATE WITH CONCAT` in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673096/use-collate-in-concat) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486804/6167855)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply! I've looked through some of the blogs and questions you posted and they have definitely helped me to understand how COLLATE works a lot more. 

I tried your fix and I'm still getting an error "Expression type smallint is invalid for COLLATE clause" which I believe is from the TransactionNumber column. I've tried to use CAST to change it to an nvarchar but it doesn't seem to work.

Again, thanks for your help!